# Preciso que uma variável do php seja colocada em um link href

Tags: php, mysql

A variável `$fa` tem que ser colocada dentro do link, mas eu não consigo fazer isso

Essa variável pega um dado do banco, está dentro do código php

```
$fa=$aux["celular"];

<a href = "https://///////////phone=$fa&text="> CLIQUE</a>
```

Comment: Precisa abrir as tags do php ou dar um echo.

Answer (score 1):

Basta interpolar as *strings*:

```
echo "<a href='http://...?phone={$phone}'></a>";
```

Perceba o uso de `{$phone}` dentro da *string*, que será substituído pelo valor da variável `$phone`.

Mas há outras considerações a se fazer. Por exemplo, o que aconteceria que o valor de `$phone` possuir o caractere `&`, tipo "0000&0000"? A saída gerada ficaria:

```
<a href='http://...?phone=0000&0000'></a>
```

Então, o valor de `phone`, na URL, seria "0000&0000" ou apenas "0000"? Para evitar comportamentos inesperados, você precisa codificar o valor antes de enviá-lo na URL:

```
$phone = urlencode($phone);
echo "<a href='http://...?phone={$phone}'></a>";
```

Pois, desta forma, a saída seria:

```
<a href='http://...?phone=0000%260000'></a>
```

Perceba que o caractere `&` foi codificado para `%26` e, assim, o valor de `phone` na URL será exatamente "0000&0000", como esperado.

Se o elemento HTML não for resultado de uma expressão PHP, você pode utilizar `<?= ?>` para evibir o valor da variável:

```
<a href='http://...?phone=<?= $phone ?>'></a>
```

Que seria o equivalente a fazer `<?php echo $phone; ?>`, mas de uma maneira mais simples.

Answer (score 0):

Se está colocando o html dando um echo no php, considere fazer desta forma, concatenando:

```
<?php
   $fa=$aux["celular"];
   echo '<a href = "https://///////////phone='.$fa.'&text=">CLIQUE</a>';
?>
```

Se está colocando o php no html, considere esta forma:

```
<?php
   $fa=$aux["celular"];
?>
<a href = "https://///////////phone=<?php echo $fa; ?>&text=">CLIQUE</a>';
```